# Laravel forward request downstream

Tags: php, laravel

I have a mobile app that needs to use Api keys in order to make requests, I however don't want to have the API keys saved to the app.
I want to use Laravel as a sort of proxy so that I can catch the request, modify it with the API keys and any other info and forward the request downstream
Any leads on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Laravel problem per-se. Consider this: when you store the APIkey somewhere in the protected storage of a mobile device, you are using an industry standard way to "secure" your secrets. If those secrets are in danger, the operating system would surely be patched.

If you inject the API key into an external web server, you are making the API key useless, since now all the incoming requests are not authenticated (you are not using an API key on your client since you are injecting it at server side).

Therefore, you are developing a public web server in which all of your resources are freely available and abusable, defeating the purpose of having an API key.